# How to run Xcode 4.3 or Xcode 3 in OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: xcode, macos

Because iOS7 needs Xcode 5, and Xcode 5 must run under OS X 10.8, if I update the OS from 10.7 to 10.8, this makes the old Xcode 4.3.3 not work.

Because an old project needs support ARMv6 arch, I still need Xcode 4.3.3 to maintain the app.
How can I have both Xcode 4 and Xcode 5?
Can Xcode 4.6/Xcode 5 can support ARMv6 arch?

Comment: Why doesn't 4.3.3 work? It's just an .app bundle Isn't it?

Comment: when open the xcode4.3.3, it will popup a message. "This installation of Xcode 4.3.3 requires Mac OS X 10.7 Lion."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Xcode 4.3 is not supported on 10.8. However, 4.4.1 (includes iOS 5.1 SDK) and 4.6.3 (includes iOS 6.1 sdk) are. Go [Apple's developer download site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode) and search for which ever newer version of Xcode 4 that works for you.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_Versions) Xcode 4.4.1 was the last to support armv6.